# Excel formulas with increasing cell references with gaps between cells with formuals in

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sorry for the lack of information in the question, but this is fairly complicatedto explain..

I'm trying to use excel to create a file for card an MSR card writing software program I've got to read.

The software must have the file in the following format;
DateTimeStamp
Track1 Data
Track2 Data
Track3 Data
Blank line

e.g.
2014.08.04    10:46:24
%123456789098?
;qweryuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm?
+1qw23er45ty67ui89op0?

The data I need to write into Track1 is prefixed with a 16 blank space, then is XccccZ (where cccc is a number padded with spaces, again as an example:

```
                X105 Z
```

I've got an excel spreadsheet which has formualas to create the format required, based on manual entry of the numbers required into a table, but I need to be able to reference sequential rows of this table from another page where the cells with the formulas in are spaced apart.

As an example, down column A in my file I have;
Row 1 - Date Time
Row 2 - =sheet1!B2
Row 3 - ;?
Row 4 - +?
Row 5 - *Blank Line*
Row 6 - Date Time
Row 7 - =sheet1!B3
Row 8 - ;?
Row 9 - +?
Row 10 - *Blank Line*
etc.

I hope this makes sense.  Whate I need is to be able to copy/paste (or fill down etc.) the first five rows as many times as required (i.e. if I have 10 cards to write, I'd need 50 rows total), and it to copy the data/formulas.  But when I do a copy/paste the cell references don't change, and when I fill down, rather than the cell reference in the formula changing by 1, it changes by 5 (accounting for the extra lines without formulas).

How can I get excel to know that the cell reference only needs to change by one each time.  I'd really like to avoid having to have five blank lines between every card number on my input table!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood well, you want "only" that the reference change by 1 every 5 rows when you copy&paste. You can use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!B"& ROW(A5)/5)
```

You take like a reference the ROW(x)/number of block rows...

Comment: That is exactly what I needed... I'd never even heard of that formula before, but it works great.  You've saved a lot of time... Thanks